# Need SQL syntax or query

Tags: sql

I have entries for 30days in table A for example below

Table A

```
activity_day    Product
-----------------------
6/1/2023 0:00   A
6/2/2023 0:00   A
6/3/2023 0:00   A
6/4/2023 0:00   A
6/5/2023 0:00   A
6/6/2023 0:00   A
6/7/2023 0:00   A
6/8/2023 0:00   A
6/9/2023 0:00   A
6/10/2023 0:00  A
6/11/2023 0:00  A
6/12/2023 0:00  A
6/13/2023 0:00  A
6/14/2023 0:00  A
6/15/2023 0:00  A
6/16/2023 0:00  A
6/17/2023 0:00  A
6/18/2023 0:00  A
6/19/2023 0:00  A
6/20/2023 0:00  A
6/21/2023 0:00  A
6/22/2023 0:00  A
6/23/2023 0:00  A
6/24/2023 0:00  A
6/25/2023 0:00  A
6/26/2023 0:00  A
6/27/2023 0:00  A
6/28/2023 0:00  A
6/29/2023 0:00  A
6/30/2023 0:00  A
```

In table B i have 4 entries for example below

Table B

```
Evaluation_day  Product Sales
------------------------------
5/29/2023 0:00  A   66
6/4/2023 0:00   A   300
6/6/2023 0:00   A   4999
6/8/2023 0:00   A   5999
```

Post joining on date and product condition i will get below values a
result set

```
activity_day    Product Sales
------------------------------
6/3/2023 0:00   A   
6/4/2023 0:00   A   300
6/5/2023 0:00   A   
6/6/2023 0:00   A   4999
6/7/2023 0:00   A   
6/8/2023 0:00   A   5999
6/9/2023 0:00   A   
6/10/2023 0:00  A   
6/11/2023 0:00  A   
6/12/2023 0:00  A   
6/13/2023 0:00  A   
6/14/2023 0:00  A   
6/15/2023 0:00  A   
6/16/2023 0:00  A   
6/17/2023 0:00  A   
6/18/2023 0:00  A   
6/19/2023 0:00  A   
6/20/2023 0:00  A   
6/21/2023 0:00  A   
6/22/2023 0:00  A   
6/23/2023 0:00  A   
6/24/2023 0:00  A   
6/25/2023 0:00  A   
6/26/2023 0:00  A   
6/27/2023 0:00  A   
6/28/2023 0:00  A   
6/29/2023 0:00  A   
6/30/2023 0:00  A
```

However for for 6/3/2023 0:00 there is null for this place i need to fill sales details from table b which is available in 5/29/2023 0:00 which is the latest entry since 6/3/2023, 6/2/2023, 6/1/2023, 6/30/2023, 6/31/2023 data is not there latest is 66 and for 6/5/2023 0:00

Could you help me with the query?

I need a SQL query for this use case

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: For `6/3/2023, 6/2/2023, 6/1/2023, 6/30/2023, 6/31/2023`, did you mean `6/3/2023, 6/2/2023, 6/1/2023, 5/30/2023, 5/31/2023`?

Comment: Please update your question with the result you want to achieve and show the SQL that you've managed to write on your own. Also, data is much more readable if you format it as tables rather than as code